# nativescript | call ngOnInit after android back button Navigation

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I have a problem handling the back button , when the user taping the back button the ngOnInit is not triggered and the component is not working as wanted .
from what i saw i understand that when taping back its only make the ngOnDestroy fire but not the ngOnInit

> ### this is the lifecycle
>
> open App --> ngOnInit() called
>
> click on some anther component --> ngOnInit() of the new component called
>
> tap back --> ngOnDestroy

Did someone had the same problem and how did you handle it ?
thank you

Comment: You could use window's ondestroy event

Comment: press back button is like navigate the rout to back component, why should ngOnInit fire?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some search i decided to use this solution

in components that i need the ngOnInit to run even if the navigate is from the back button or function i added this

```
constructor(private location : PlatformLocation) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.location.onPopState(() => {
    this.initComponent();
});
}
```

Comment: This will not distinguish where you came from ... 
Sometimes , you want to do different logic based on the previous page you were on.... ( you can check the path/url though)

Comment: Also  , consider this : `A---navigateTo-->B--navigateTo---->--navigateTo----->C----navigateTo--->A` , with my code you can detect A------->A situation.

Comment: But it's a nice solution for simple things

Comment: thanks !, its seems to work fine for now but ill test it a bit more and if its not work as i wanted ill replace it to you solution

Comment: i solved it using 
 ```this.location.onPopState(() => {
    this.initComponent();
});```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you think  `ngOnInit` should run on back ?  it doesn't

Solution is to use router events :

For example : A Solution to detect `back` from `"/beatles/john/songs/strawberryfields"` to `"/doors/jim/girlfriend/pam"`

```
Doors page --------> Beatles page.....(back tapped)----------->Doors
```

Is :

Add this method into a shared service :

```
 public onNavigatePreviousToCurrent(pre: string, current: string  ): Observable<any>
        {
            return this.router.events.pipe(filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd), pairwise(), filter((f: [any, any]) =>
                                                                                                       {
                                                                                                           return f[0].url.toLowerCase()
                                                                                                                      .indexOf(pre.toLowerCase()) > -1 &&
                                                                                                                  f[1].url.toLowerCase()
                                                                                                                      .indexOf(current.toLowerCase()) > -1;
                                                                                                       })  );
        }
```

In the Doors page call it :

```
 ngOnInit()
        {
            let f = this._routingService.onNavigatePreviousToCurrent("john", "pam") //or doors or jim
                        .subscribe((res) =>
                                   {
                                    //do what you want here !!!
                                   }, (error) =>
                                   {
                                   });

   //don't forget to unsubscribe `f`
       }
```

Notice that you can use any token from `/beatles/john/songs/strawberryfields` ( `beatles`,`john`,`songs`,`strawberryfields` , `atles`)----> also in Doors.  (substring)

Basically this methods detects where you came from and what is the destination after `back`.

BTW you might want to say : "well , I don't know where I am , I only want a situation where a user tapped "back".

Answer :

```
this._routingService.onNavigatePreviousToCurrent("/", "pam") ;
// "/" will always be present , so basically this ^ detects back from anywhere to Doors page
```